# Overlapping intervals of a Poisson arrival process

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Calls arrives according to a Poisson arrival process with rate $\lambda = 15$. Find $E(N(2,4]N(3,5])$

My thoughts: $E(N(2,4]) = E(N(3,5]) = \lambda * t = 15 * 2 = 30$
However, I cannot figure out the next step, since $(2,4]$ and $(3,5]$ are NOT non-overlapping, so they are NOT independent and I cannot get the resulting expectation by simply multiplying them.

I'm really stuck in this. Can someone please explain this problem? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of arrivals between $2$ and $3$, $Y$ the number between $3$ and $4$, and $Z$ the number between $4$ and $5$.

We want $E((X+Y)(Y+Z))$. Expand, and use the linearity of expectation. Almost everything is simple, except that we need $E(Y^2)$. You can write this down easily if you already know the variance of the Poisson, since $\text{Var}(Y)=E(Y^2)-(E(Y))^2$.

Comment: You are welcome. I am confident you know enough to finish.

Comment: Hi, could you please give a look at another problem I just encountered. I'd appreciate a lot. Thanks! http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1209698/213791

Comment: the link is posted above. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I was away, Friday night, time for dancing not mathematics. I notice you got an answer.

Comment: Haha yes I think he's correct.