# Second moments from survival function

Tags: probability, self-learning

Let X be a non-negative continuous random variable with probability density function f(x). Let $$G(t) = \int_{t}^{\infty} f(x)dx$$
Show that$$E(X^{2}) = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} tG(t)dt$$

My thoughts:
I know that $$E(X^{2}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2}f(x)dx$$, so here I need to prove $$x^{2}f(x)dx = tG(t)dt$$
I'm stuck in this step. Can someone explain how to prove this problem? Any clue would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit more complicated than that. Change the order of integration:
$$\begin{align*}
E(X^2) &= \int_0^{\infty} x^2 f(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^x 2t f(x) \, dt \, dx \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} \int_t^{\infty} 2t f(x) \, dx \, dt \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} 2t G(t) \, dt,
\end{align*}$$
as required.

(It may be more obvious if you read the string of equalities starting from the bottom.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain how do you get the second line from the third line?

Comment: I changed the order of integration: the domain of integration is $0 <t <x <\infty$, so the new inner integral is of $x$ from $t $ to $\infty$.

Comment: In the first line, the lower limit should be negative infinity instead of 0. Is there a problem...

Comment: Your question states that $X$ is a non-negative RV, so I started at $0$.

Comment: I'm still not sure why after changing order the range of t becomes (0,x)?

Comment: Ah, that line is writing $x^2-0=\int_0^{\infty} 2t \, dt$, which you know by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.