# Darth Vader Rule for Expectations

Tags: probability

If $X$ is uniform on $[0, 1]$, how can I compute the expected value of $X^2$ using the fact that the expectation of $X$ equals $\int_0^\infty P(X > x)$ ?

First I find $P(X^2 < x)$ and I get $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{y}} dx = \sqrt{y} $. Then $P(X^2 > x) = 1 - \sqrt{y}$. But the integral I said earlier will diverge. What's wrong?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209698/second-moments-from-survival-function

Answer (score 1):

$$EX^{2}=\int_0^{\infty} P(X^{2} >x)dx=\int_0^{\infty} P(X >\sqrt x)dx$$ $$=\int_0^{1} P(X >\sqrt x)dx$$ because $P(X>1)=0$ if $x >1$. Hence $EX^{2}=\int_0^{1} (1-\sqrt x) dx=\frac 1 3$.